# Why silverstripe 4 base_tag returning http instead of https?

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am using Silverstripe 4. I have base_tag on my template SS file. Website is being accessed using https. For example: https://website.com

When I check the viewer code, base_tag is retrieved using Director::absoluteBaseURL()

When I call Director::absoluteBaseURL(), it return "https://website.com"

However on my base_tag, it always appear

I am using Heroku to host my app (if this information can be any help)

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Do you have SS_BASE_URL defined in your `.env` file?

Comment: Yeap, I defined the SS_BASE_URL with https.

Answer (score 2):

For all the SS4 project I have had to insert into `{root-folder}/app/_config.php` the following:

```
// Hack to allow SS to insert the correct base url as defined by environmental variable 'SS_BASE_URL'.
$url = getenv('SS_BASE_URL');

if (isset($url) && $url != '') {
    Director::config()->set('alternate_base_url', (rtrim($url, '/') . '/'));
    Director::config()->set('cookie_path', '/');
}
```

and make sure that `.env` in the root folder has declared `SS_BASE_URL`

```
SS_BASE_URL="https://www.***.com"
```

If you are using Docker (Docker Compose) add:

```
  environment:
    - SS_BASE_URL=https://www.***.com
```

to your docker compose file.